# Provide 'Example Value' for swagger.yaml object with optional fields

Tags: model, swagger

I am trying to provide more description in the 'Model' tab and example values in the  'Example Value' tab for a swagger.yaml object with optional objects

My model to be used by my PATCH request (RestAPI) is defined like so in my swagger.yaml:

```
  mymodel:
    items:  
      - $ref: '#/definitions/modelHeader'
      - $ref: '#/definitions/modelPayload'
```

Currently mymodel has
'Model' as "mymodel {}" and 'Example Value' as "{}"

modelHeader and modelPayload are composite objects with examples defined.
Even though mymodel does not mandate any field, I want it to display these optional fields with examples.

I know I can define a minimal the example like so         `example: [{name: 'myname', value: 'myvalue1'},{name: 'myname2', value: 'myvalue2'}]`

But that is cumbersome and still does not populate 'Model'.
Is it possible to provide a url to a json as an example?

Any hints or ideas would be appreciated. I am still new to YAML specification

Comment: Your spec is not valid. Is `mymodel` supposed to be an array containing `modelHeader` and `modelPayload` objects, or a combined object containing properties from both `modelHeader` and `modelPayload`?

Comment: My spec does not throw errors at [editor.swagger.io](http://editor.swagger.io/#) so I believe it is valid. I intended mymodel to be an object using 'allOf' but it threw errors in yaml so I changed it to an array. The product functionality works with that

Comment: *changed it to a dictionary

Comment: I wouldn't bother too much with the YAML specification. Your YAML is valid, it is the interpretation that swagger does of the parsed YAML, with specific swagger-ish expectations that goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spec is not valid, because `items` require a single type and not an array of types:

```
items:
  type: string

# or

items:
  $ref: '#/definitions/something'
```

> I intended mymodel to be an object using 'allOf'

The correct syntax for `allOf` is:

```
  mymodel:
    allOf:  
      - $ref: '#/definitions/modelHeader'
      - $ref: '#/definitions/modelPayload'
```

`allOf` reuses the `example`s from each model. For example, if the base models are defined as follows:

```
  modelHeader:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        example: 1

  modelPayload:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        example: Alice
```

`mymodel` gets this example:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Alice"
}
```

[image: Swagger Editor - example for an allOf model]

Comment: Thanks @Helen. I don't know why Swagger editor did not throw errors for my use of items. But allOf works for me now. Thanks for pointing it out! It did not work before may be because of some irrelevant change :)